# Where should I ask questions about postal mail?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I tried to search for the best place to ask but I cant find the best site.

I own a condo in Florida and I get spam/unwanted by mail and I want it to stop, so my box is getting full and it look suspicious for others passing by

I look at the USPS (united state postal service) but no luck, and I tried to look everywhere as well and I want to get rid of this mail.

So is there a Stack Exchange site that I can ask this question?

Comment: You want a way to stop receiving spam? Novel idea

Comment: Questions about postal mail are only answered by the StackExchange network via postal mail. The address is unlisted.

Comment: Call up your local postmaster.  Myself, I just tracked down everybody who sent me spam mail and ... well, lets just say I beat them to death.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is no site on the Stack Exchange network on which this is an on-topic question.

<sub>(Googling *"stop junk mail"* turns up lots of potentially-useful information.  Good luck.)</sub>

Comment: What if this were no longer true?